# Outlook 365 meeting requests received & marked tentative automatically, but the actual request going to delegate

Tags: outlook, calendar

In Outlook 365, my boss receives meeting requests that are being marked tentative automatically, but the actual request is coming to me as her delegate. She cannot respond to the invite.

Comment: I believe all meeting requests are tentative by default. Does an actual tentative response go out to whoever sent the invite? If not, then this is normal behaviour. So is you getting all her meeting invites as her delegate. You may also wish to elaborate on the issue of "she cannot respond to the invite" as in what happens exactly? The option is disabled in her calendar? She can't see her calendar? She responds, but the response bounces (rejected by server)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on testing in my lab, It seems your boss has set up with the default delegate access "Send requests to my delegate only, but send a copy to me".

Open your boss's mailbox,locate Account setting, click delegate access:[image]

Then your boss can response meeting request.

Comment: How about your issue? Have your issue been resolved? you could mark the helpful reply as best answer, your action will be helpful to someone who encounter the same issue, they could find solution quickly.